# Jquery - validate multiple fields (grouped fields) where all fields are to be valid

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate, wicket

I have been working on getting the validation of multiple fields to work in a generic manner. My form has a parent span which has two textfields, when one or both the textfields fail validation, the span should be highlighted with errorclass, in my case a red box around the two textfields and the span should be unhighlighted when both the fields are valid. But the actual behaviour is that, if the first textbox is given a valid value the jquery highlight/unhighlight function is removing the errorClass/redbox around the two fields even though the required/regex validation of the second field is not passed yet. I have written a custom method and added an extra validation rule for both the texboxes, grouped the tesboxes, but none are working, i'm actually a newbie to jquery and couldn't proceed from where i'm now,  so any help is highly appreciated.

Sample code here

setUpValidations : function () {

```
    $.validator.addMethod(
        'regex', function(value, element, param) {
            var regex = new RegExp(param);
            return regex.test(value);
        }, 'Regex failed'
    );

   $.validator.addMethod(
        'validateGroupFields', function(value, element) {
        var spanElement = $(element).closest('span');
        var spanChildren = listChildren(spanElement);
        var result = true;
                   spanChildren.each( function(index, value) {
            //alert("index" + index + "value" + value);
                if((this).valid() == true)
                {   
                    $(this).siblings('div.errorbuble1').hide();
                }else {
                    result = false;
                }
            });
            return result;
        }, 'Group validation failed'
    );

function listChildren(element) {
        var children = $(element).find(':input');
        return children;
    };

    $.validator.setDefaults({

        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('span').attr('class','error');
        },

        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('span').attr('class','');
        },

        onfocusout: function(element, event) {
            if ( !this.checkable(element) || !this.optional(element)) {
                this.element(element);
                $(element).siblings('div.errorbuble1').hide();
            }
        },

        onfocusin: function(element) {
            if( (element.name in this.submitted) && !$(element).valid()){
                    $(element).siblings('div.errorbuble1').show();
            }
        },

        onclick: function(element, event) {
        // click on selects, radiobuttons and checkboxes
            if(element.type === 'radio' || element.type === 'checkbox'){
                this.element(element);
            }
            else if( (element.name in this.submitted)){ //select
                this.element(element);
            }
        },


    });
},

 onValidate : function () {

    $('#form11').validate({
        errorClass: 'newError',

       submithandler: function(form11){
          (form11).submit();
       },

       invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        submitted = true;
        },

       rules : {
               'errorIndicator2:textField3':{
                 required:true,
                 regex : { 
                     param : /^[0-9]+$/
                 },
         validateGroupFields: true
             },
             'errorIndicator2:textField4':{
                 required:true,
                 regex : { 
                     param : /^[a-z]+$/
                 },
              validateGroupFields: true
             },
           },
          groups: {
    nameGroup: "errorIndicator2:textField3
             errorIndicator2:textField4"
        },

           showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            this.defaultShowErrors();
            if (submitted) {
                $('div.errorbuble1').hide();
                submitted = false;
            }
        },

           errorElement: "div",
       wrapper: "div", // a wrapper around the error message

       errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

            offset = element.offset();

            error.addClass('errorbuble1');  // add a class to the wrapper
            error.css('position', 'absolute');
            error.css('left', offset.left + (element.outerWidth()) + 5);
            error.css('top', offset.top + (element.outerHeight())/3);   
            error.insertAfter(element);  
       },


           var submitted = false;
       $(document).ready(function(){

JavaScriptValidator.setUpValidations();
JavaScriptValidator.onValidate();

$("[type=submit]").on({
    click: function(event) {
    JavaScriptValidator.onValidate();
    }
    });
});


 <h3>Error box around two fields:</h3> 
<span wicket:id="errorIndicator2"> 
<table>
    <tbody><tr>
    <td>Number:</td><td><input wicket:id="textField3" name="errorIndicator2:textField3" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Alpha</td><td><input wicket:id="textField4" name="errorIndicator2:textField4" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
<!-- error popup div gets added here -->
```

Comment: Can you supply some sample html that you are using. possibly a jsFiddle? im nearly sure that you have a `this` mis-used in one of your functions.

Comment: I believe this is a bug with the validate plugin - https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/364 I ended up having to ceate a custom validation method with `addMethod` that was very specific to the grouped inputs which obviously isn't ideal but did the job at the time.

Answer (score 1):

In the unhighlight function you must check if all the other fields in the same container are valid before removing the error class from the container. Something like

```
$('input,select', $(element).closest('span')).not(element)
```

should select all the other form elements in the same container. However, you *might* run into recursion problems (I haven't tried your situation, but see the [discssion](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/412) on the require_from_group method).

Also, you should not set classes via the attr method.  The element may have other classes for other purposes which you would remove when you set/unset the error class.  use the jQuery addClass and removeClass functions instead:

```
$(element).closest('span').addClass('error');
$(element).closest('span').removeClass('error');
```

Comment: this is useful - see my answer which addresses recursion problems

Answer (score 1):

Calling a validating method like element(), $(...).valid(), or form() inside the highlight callback will result in infinite loop, but you can use the validator instance property 'invalid' which maintains a list of invalid fields.

```
$("form").validate({
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).closest('div.container').addClass('errorClass');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        var validator = this, result = true;

        // check for invalid elements here
        $(element).closest('div.container').find(':input').each(function () {
            if (validator.invalid[this.name] !== undefined) {
                result = false;
            }
        });
        if (result) {
            $(element).closest('div.container').removeClass('errorClass')
        }
    }
});
```

thanks @Adam set me on the right track [**fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/kYZHY/2/)

Comment: This looks good.  Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem in require-from-group where we *need* to revalidate the other fields. There are ways to avoid the obvious infinite loop that I maybe should have mentioned.  For example: if( !$(element).data('reval') ){ $(all_elements_in_group).data('reval', true); $(others_in_group).valid(); $(all_elements_in_group).data('reval', false); }  However, there is still a recursion problem and a discussion at the link in my answer.  Your solution is better for your problem :)